# React library to display unified diff between two strings

Tags: reactjs, git, components, diff

I am looking for a React component that shows a unified git-like diff between two strings (specifically, two different JSON snippets).

Like this:
[image: unified git diff example]

I am currently using the react-ace diff component, but that only does a side-by-side comparison and also doesn't take into account what has been added or removed.

Answer (score 7):

Try either "react-diff-view" or "react-diff-viewer".

The "react-diff-viewer" is quite simple to use/implement while the "react-diff-view" offers some more advanced features.

It's up to you, here the links:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-diff-viewer
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-diff-view

Comment: it's unable to handle large file comparison though.

Comment: so I figured that if you use stringify then do stringify(jsoninput, null, 2) and the do the json comparison, it'll be much faster.

Answer (score 3):

[react-diff-viewer-continued](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-diff-viewer-continued?activeTab=versions) might be what you are looking for since 'react-diff-view' is no longer having updates and is [not compactable for react 18^](https://github.com/praneshr/react-diff-viewer/issues/166).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34103478)

Comment: I appreciate the link!